# How to configure Liferay using Consul

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, consul

We use Liferay 6.2 Portal in our application.
We want to update properties in portal-ext.properties with values taken from Consul.
For example, we want to set property virtual.hosts.valid.hosts with values from Consul.
One option we want to avoid is using Consul-template and update the file using bash scripts.

Is there a programmatic way to update properties in Liferay? (From hook, for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no easy programmatic way to configure Liferay properties programmatically, we decided to modify startup sh scripts to read data from Consul and update configuration in our custom portal-ext.properties

Answer (score 2):

You could use [conf.d](http://www.confd.io/). It is basically a tilny configuration manager that can get configuration from etcd or consul and write it to local files.
I've used it to be able to configure a Kubernetes cluster of Liferay instances. I don't have a standalone example but [here is](https://github.com/milendyankov/liferay-infrastructure-as-code-demo/blob/master/containerized/CoreOS_vagrant/provisioning/worker/cloud-config.yml) the code (from CoseOS's cloud config) that creates conf.d configuration files.

Comment: I would prefer to avoid any changes to file system. If there is no way to change Liferay properties programmatically, we can change them using bash scripts - but this is something we want to avoid.

Comment: Doing that programmatically is possible but complex. You will have to replace / extend Liferay to load properties from consul directly (look for ConfigurationFactory and ConfigurationFactoryImpl)

Comment: Do you mean that I'll need to provide my own implementation of ConfigurationFactoryImpl and replace Liferay's class in the classpath?

Comment: Also note that you'll have to implement a notification mechanism to trigger restart when properties have changed. This may sound easy but once you try you'll quickly hit some edge cases. Same thing applies for shell scripts by the why that is why I decided to use conf.d

Comment: There a few ways to approach it but almost certainly you'll end up overwriting / replacing classes. Liferay provides EXT for that purpose so it's not that you have to recompile the whole portal from source. 

That said I haven't tried to do such thing myself so I give no guarantee it will work. Just based on my knowledge I think it should be doable but quite complex.

Answer (score 0):

Some properties can be updated dynamically through a hook. You can find them in the dtd for liferay-hook.xml. just create a hook and look up the dtd url (I'm currently on my phone, no good access to resources like this url)

Comment: Thank you, but DTD states that it allows to change only specific set of properties, and the one I need is not in the list.
Also, I need to send REST request to external service (from Java code) to get desired value.

Comment: For all the properties not listed in the dtd, you'll need to restart the appserver   or implement the update yourself. It might be possible but just not implemented. I doubt that the non dynamic properties have no api to change them

Comment: I have no problem restarting. I just want to avoid changing anything in file system to configure Liferay, so I need a way to change values of some properties during Liferay startup.

Comment: "Some" is the keyword here. For some properties it will be easy, for some it won't. Go with Milen's idea, however I don't know what business value you assume when you're not writing to the file system. In fact, I wouldn't worry. You can configure through a separate consul-exclusive properties file - way easier than your plan I guess